# how to connect javascript files in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

My problem is not to work javascript.
my javascript files are in public/javascripts

*app.js*

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

*views/layout.pug*

```
doctype html
 html
  head
    title Sunghee
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css', integrity='sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M', crossorigin='anonymous')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', integrity='sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN', crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js', integrity='sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4', crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js', integrity='sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1', crossorigin='anonymous')
    //- script(src='https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/layout.css')
    script(src='/javascripsts/layout.js')
    block css      
    block script
```

*views/events/new.pug*

```
extends ../layout

block css
  link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/events/new.min.css')

block script
  script(src='/javascripts/events/new.js')
```

*public/javascripsts/events/new.js*

```
$(function(){
   tinymce.init({
   seletor: '#mytextarea'
  });
});
```

Not all of the JavaScript files work, as well as this file.
There is `"jquery": "^3.2.1"` in "dependencies" at package.json
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistypings? On your *views/layout.pug*:

script(src='/javascrip**s**ts/layout.js')